# How to use CASE and HAVING clauses efficiently to optimize SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, case-statement, having-clause

I have a SQL Query i.e.

```
SELECT 
    A2P.aid,
    COUNT(*) [PaperCount],
    [2010] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2010 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2011] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2011 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2014] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    sub_aminer_author2paper A2P
WHERE 
    aid IN (SELECT 
                aid 
            FROM 
                sub_aminer_author 
            WHERE 
                paper_count >= 20
           )
AND A2P.p_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2014
GROUP BY 
    A2P.aid
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT A2P.pid) >= 2
ORDER BY 
    A2P.aid
```

Now, the issue is I want to have rows in output containing value >= 2 in each column i.e. `2010`, `2011`, `2012`, `2013`, and `2014` OR the values in column `Paper_Count` >= 10 for each row in output.

Moreover, I have used the condition as:

```
HAVING 
        COUNT(DISTINCT A2P.pid) >= 2
```

But results are not as desired. See the image for output...
[image]

As it is clear that `0` values are also retrieved in output which is not desired.

Please help in this regard.
Thanks!

Comment: "optimize" and "efficiently" don't seem to relate to your problem. Maybe edit the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query your Select for your conditions:

```
Select A2P.aid, [PaperCount], [2010, [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014]
From (
    SELECT 
        A2P.aid,
        COUNT(*) [PaperCount],
        [2010] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2010 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [2011] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2011 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [2014] = SUM(CASE WHEN A2P.p_year = 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    FROM 
        sub_aminer_author2paper A2P
    WHERE 
        aid IN (SELECT aid FROM sub_aminer_author WHERE paper_count >= 20)
    AND A2P.p_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2014
    GROUP BY 
        A2P.aid
) x
Where [2010] >= 2 and [2011] >= 2 and [2012] >= 2 and [2013] >= 2 and [2014] >= 2;
```

Or something like this:

```
Select aid
    , [PaperCount] = [2010] + [2011] + [2012] + [2013] + [2014]
    , [2010], [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014]
From (
    SELECT aid, p_year
    FROM @sub_aminer_author2paper A2P
    WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM @sub_aminer_author WHERE paper_count >= 20)
        AND p_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2014
    GROUP BY A2P.aid, A2P.p_year
)p
Pivot (
    count(p_year)
    For p_year In ([2010], [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014])
) as piv
Where [2010] >= 2 and [2011] >= 2 and [2012] >= 2 and [2013] >= 2 and [2014] >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Julien

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled from different sources and optimized my query if someone wishes to see how I achieved it. Please have a look at this.
https://junaidtechblog.wordpress.com/2019/09/04/optimize-sql-query-groupby-having/